# Can I host Angular2 frontend and Golang backend in one server

Tags: go, angular, frontend, backend

I want to create RESTful API with Golang and frontend with Angular2.
Communication will be made with http requests. Angular2 will send requests to Golang API's. I know for Angular2 I should run own http server for routing and services.

Can I run Golang server on one host and Angular2 server on another one and connect them together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular2 applications correspond to a set of static files (dependencies and application code). To have your application served by Go, you need to add some code to serve these files.

It seems possible. See this link:

- https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/HttpStaticFiles

**Edit**

Following your comment:

> If you want to host Angular2 and golang in one server. For example i will have access to web site with link mywebsite.com and access to golang api api.mywebsite.com

I can't see any reason not to do that. Just be careful to support CORS in your API (send the CORS headers in the response and support prefligthed requests). See these links:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors
- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/

Comment: One can even include those assets into the binary, using things like [bindata-assetfs](https://github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs) or [go.rice](https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice).

Comment: I want to use golang and angular2 separatly. Golang server will send only json data. Angular will request data from golang server api's and render web pages. Can i host  angular and golang in one server? For example  i will have access to web site with link http://mywebsite.com and access to golang api http://api.mywebsite.com

Comment: I can't see any reason not to do that. Just be careful to support CORS in your API. See http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/

Answer (score 6):

Actual implementation with the stadand library

```
type Adapter func(http.Handler) http.Handler

// Adapt function to enable middlewares on the standard library
func Adapt(h http.Handler, adapters ...Adapter) http.Handler {
    for _, adapter := range adapters {
        h = adapter(h)
    }
    return h
}

// Creates a new serve mux
mux := http.NewServeMux()

// Create room for static files serving
mux.Handle("/node_modules/", http.StripPrefix("/node_modules", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./node_modules"))))
mux.Handle("/html/", http.StripPrefix("/html", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./html"))))
mux.Handle("/js/", http.StripPrefix("/js", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./js"))))
mux.Handle("/ts/", http.StripPrefix("/ts", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./ts"))))
mux.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css"))))

// Do your api stuff**
mux.Handle("/api/register", Adapt(api.RegisterHandler(mux),
    api.GetMongoConnection(),
    api.CheckEmptyUserForm(),
    api.EncodeUserJson(),
    api.ExpectBody(),
    api.ExpectPOST(),

))
mux.HandleFunc("/api/login", api.Login)
mux.HandleFunc("/api/authenticate", api.Authenticate)

// Any other request, we should render our SPA's only html file,
// Allowing angular to do the routing on anything else other then the api    
// and the files it needs for itself to work.
// Order here is critical. This html should contain the base tag like
// <base href="/"> *href here should match the HandleFunc path below 
mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "html/index.html")
})
```